# Attribute “titleTextStyle” has already been defined in android studio

Tags: android

My android application has no problem but when i am trying to build app i got the lot of error Attribute titleTextStyle has already been defined and same another attributes error.

Here these dependencies i am using in my app.

```
    dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
    }
```